# How to get WiFi MAC asdress on Windows Store App

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, wifi-direct

I am looking for some api. 
Can I get WiFi HotSpot MAC address on Windows Store APP ? 
I know this is not possible in Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in Windows Store apps either. This is at least partially because it would allow you to find the approximate location of users based on the nearby access points.